# pyhdb encoding issue on Python

Tags: python, encoding, connection

I am trying to use Python to connect to the HANA Cloud. I can access to the database using the code below, but after I execute the code `ab = cursor.fetchall()`. It got the encoding error. Anyone know how to solve this issue and give me some guide how to change the coding? Much appreciate!

```
import pyhdb
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

connection = pyhdb.connect('localhost', 3333, 'User', 'PWD')
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("""
       SELECT * FROM ggggg.LIFESTYLES_SURVEY_2017 where 
       DIETARY_SHOP_VEGETARIAN = 'Vegetarian'
       UNION
       SELECT TOP 3000 * FROM CRM_AGILE.LIFESTYLES_SURVEY_2017 where 
       DIETARY_SHOP_VEGETARIAN != 'Vegetarian'
       ORDER BY RAND()
       """)

ab = cursor.fetchall()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are messing with encoding in python somehow.
To help you more, we need, and it's important, your python version (show when you open a python terminal)

Did you try running your execute(***) code without line break ? (one-line)

Comment: Hi Skapin, thanks for your response. I am using Python 3.6.2. "cursor.execute" I can execute this code successfully (I have tried one-line and without line both execute successfully). Do you know how to encoding in Pyhdb?

Comment: The issue I think probably is about my dataset has special symbol like emoji or character. Would you know how to encoding in pyhdb? I search a lot but can't find anything about pyhdb encoding.